# JavaScript - Swapping an elements class with another

Tags: javascript

I am experiencing hell right now trying to accomplish the most basic thing. I've researched and attempted using replace, classLists etc, but cannot get it to work. NOTE: To any who can help, I do not want to use JQuery as I'm still learning JavaScript.

My Goal: To swap the elements that have a class of "hot" to cold, and a class of "cold" to hot < Inside the "unordered list" element "groceries".

```
function swapClass(){

 document.getElementById("groceries").querySelectorAll(".hot").classList.toggle("cold");
 document.getElementById("groceries").querySelectorAll(".cold").classList.toggle("hot");}
```

Much appreciation. I hope I am on the right lines somewhere. I had also attempted a for loop but realised surely that is not even necessary. and also tried.

Comment: What result are you getting?

Comment: @Kinduser there most definitely is https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: In this way, aren't you toggling hot->cold first, and then immediately toggling all original .cold plus all recently-toggled cold->hot again right away?

Comment: @Soviut I'm surprised. Whole life in a lie.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to do it in two steps:

1. Get the list of `hot` elements and `cold` elements.
2. Swap them.

Here's one way to do it:

```
function swapClass() {
  // We'll be using these variables in a few places, so let's define them here.
  var i, element;

  // Get a reference to the top-level element.
  var groceriesElement = document.getElementById("groceries");

  // Get a list of hot and cold elements.
  var hotElements = groceriesElement.querySelectorAll(".hot");
  var coldElements = groceriesElement.querySelectorAll(".cold");

  // Swap the class names.
  for (i = 0; i < hotElements.length; i++) {
    element = hotElements[i];
    element.classList.add("cold");
    element.classList.remove("hot");
  }
  for (i = 0; i < coldElements.length; i++) {
    element = coldElements[i];
    element.classList.add("hot");
    element.classList.remove("cold");
  }
}
```

Note that [`classList` isn't supported in older browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=classlist), but that may not matter to you. If it does, you can include [a polyfill](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills#classlist).

Answer (score 1):

MDN will become your best friend, they have full documentation of all Web APIs you can think of.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

`querySelectorAll()` returns a NodeList, which is similar to a JS array. There is no `classList` property on this type, so you will have to operate on each element in the NodeList.

That's the big issue here, the other one is the way you are performing the swap. You are toggling (removing if present, and adding if not present) the 'cold' class on all '.hot' elements, then toggling the 'hot' class on all '.cold' elements. If you expect no elements to have both hot and cold before this operation (which it seems based on your question), then the result is that all '.hot' elements are now '.cold', and all '.cold' elements are now '.cold' and '.hot'. Picture this, you have 4 elements:

```
<div class="hot"></div>
<div class="hot"></div>
<div class="cold"></div>
<div class="cold"></div>
```

The first statement in your function executes. You take all hot elements and toggle cold, resulting in this:

```
<div class="hot cold"></div>
<div class="hot cold"></div>
<div class="cold"></div>
<div class="cold"></div>
```

Then you take all cold elements and toggle hot, resulting in this:

```
<div class="cold"></div>
<div class="cold"></div>
<div class="cold hot"></div>
<div class="cold hot"></div>
```

What you want to do is get the full list, then toggle both classes on the one list:

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll('#groceries .hot, #groceries .cold');
list.forEach(el => el.classList.toggle('hot'));
list.forEach(el => el.classList.toggle('cold'));
```

Comment: `groceries` needs a hash (#).  Otherwise, this is probably the most concise answer.

Comment: Right okay that kinda makes sense. My lecturer is teaching us web in the most misleading and horrible way, and as I have to follow some function tests, I assumed (like the others) it'll only be a few lines of code in which it isn't, and the way he tests them is extremely tedious. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`querySelectorAll()` returns a NodeList, so you'll have to iterate through each item in the list:

```
function swapClass()
{
   var groceries = document.getElementById("groceries");
   var hotItems = groceries.querySelectorAll(".hot");
   var coldItems = groceries.querySelectorAll(".cold");

   for (var item of hotItems)
   {
       item.classList.add("cold");
       item.classList.remove("hot");
   }

   for(var item of coldItems)
   {
       item.classList.add("hot");
       item.classList.remove("cold");
   }
}
```

Comment: Right okay I feel like there would have been more steps as I said before I had tried using for loops etc, but due to the way my lecturer is teaching/testing JavaScript, I assumed it would be a couple lines of code (like the other functions) he has written for us.. Also, I modified the code to match that above but I still result in element 1 (expecting hot, resulted cold) and element 4 (expected cold, resulted hot)?